# Why is object_usage_linter() only checking functions if they are assigned

Tags: r, lintr

#### Example

```
# without assignment: no lint
lintr::lint(text = "function() x",
            linters = lintr::object_usage_linter())

# with assignment: lint
lintr::lint(text = "myfun <- function() x",
            linters = lintr::object_usage_linter())
#> <text>:1:21: warning: [object_usage_linter] no visible binding for global variable 'x'
#> myfun <- function() x
#>                     ^
```

In cases like `lapply` where I often use an anonymous function, lintr does not check those functions.

```
lintr::lint(text = "lapply(1:3, FUN = function() x)",
            linters = lintr::object_usage_linter())
```

Can I enable lintr to check those cases, as well? And out of curiosity: What is the reasoning behind that behaviour?

Comment: What version of `lintr` are you using?

Comment: I am using version '3.1.0'

Comment: I updated lintr to the latest release 3.1.1 but to no avail